# MS Access+update Oracle SQL database from excel file

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have a Front end app created in MS Access and a back-end supported by an Oracle database.
The users are required to upload an Excel file (around 6000 rows) every day and the process is done currently like this:

- we have a temporary table where a VBA code is moving the excel data (the table is empty at every load)
- once the file is uploaded another VBA code is pulling the data from that table and moves it using DAO to the server, line by line

The process takes a huge amount of time and we need to speed up the process.
The existing code with some adjustments and fields not presented here:

```
Public Function import_to_dwh_old_1() As Boolean
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim bol As Boolean
    Dim strSQL_hr As Object
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varReturn As Variant
    Dim HR_ID As String

    '######## 05/26/2019 - Fix to upload multiple times per day the HR file
    db.Execute ("DELETE FROM DISPUTE_MGMT.DD_HR WHERE SNAPSHOT='" & Format(GetUTC(), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'")
    '######## End fix to upload ###########
    
    bol = True
    strSQL = "Select * FROM temp_hr"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("DISPUTE_MGMT_DD_HR")
      
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst
    
    cnt = rst.RecordCount
    i = 1
    
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        On Error GoTo capture_error
        
        'varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, "Uploading dispute " & i & " out of " & cnt & " for snapshot [" & Format(GetUTC(), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "]")
        rs.AddNew
       
        rs!USER_NAME = Environ("USERNAME")
        rs!IS_DELETED = 0
        rs!DATE_CREATED = GetUTC()
        rs!DATE_MODIFIED = GetUTC()
        rs!SNAPSHOT = Format(GetUTC(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        rs!HR_ID = rst!ID
        
        '### deleted fields from code
               
        rs.Update
        
        rst.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, " ")
    
    import_to_dwh = True
    Exit Function
    
capture_error:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    MsgBox Err.Description & " - HR_ID = " & HR_ID
    varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, " ")
    import_to_dwh = False
    Exit Function
End Function
```

The new idea is more direct but I am not sure how to use in the same time a MS Access table and a SQL database table in the same statement

```
Public Function import_to_dwh() As Boolean
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
       
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    If env = "prod" Then
        qdf.Connect = prod_credentials
    Else
        qdf.Connect = dev_credentials
    End If
    
    'Delete current snapshot
    qdf.SQL = "DELETE FROM DISPUTE_MGMT.DD_HR WHERE SNAPSHOT='" & Format(GetUTC(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & "';"
    Debug.Print qdf.SQL
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdf.Execute
    
    qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO DISPUTE_MGMT.DD_HR (USER_NAME, IS_DELETED, DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED, SNAPSHOT, HR_ID) SELECT '" & Environ("USERNAME") & "', 0, to_date('" & GetUTC() & "','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), to_date('" & GetUTC() & "','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'), " _
              & "'" & Format(GetUTC(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & "', ID FROM temp_hr;"
    Debug.Print qdf.SQL
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdf.Execute
    
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rst Is Nothing Then
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        qdf.Close
        Set qdf = Nothing
    End If
    import_to_dwh = True
    'If Not db Is Nothing Then Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: " & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Dim L As Long
    For L = 0 To Errors.Count - 1
        Debug.Print Errors(L) & " - " & Errors(L).Description
    Next
    import_to_dwh = False
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Obviously, the second method does not work.. Could someone point me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: Why the temp table?  Why not have your code go directly from Excel to Oracle?

Comment: We use a MS Access database, and that is how the app was built at that moment. Now we need to change it so that we improve the performance..

Comment: That's my point.  You can likely improve performance by eliminating the temp table step.

Comment: the update of the temp table takes 3seconds, the upload to SQL takes 30min.. so eliminating that step will not help.. the issue is not there..

Comment: There is nothing "obvious" about the 2nd method not working. You can INSERT into a linked ODBC table from a local table without problems. See here to help find the issue: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) -- Edit: you need a local query, though, not a Pass-through query.

Comment: Note though that inserting records into linked tables with DAO recordsets and `.AddNew` is usually very fast. 6000 records shouldn't take longer than a few seconds on a LAN. So there may be something else going on here. -- Maybe try a simple process with a simple, new table.

Comment: My question is: can I use a INSERT INTO .. SELECT within VBA, where INSERT INTO table is from SQL and the selection is done from ms access table? without any linked table?

Comment: To insert with an Access query, you need a linked table. `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("DISPUTE_MGMT_DD_HR")` indicates that you have one.

Comment: I was speaking the second option.. the first one is terribly slow..